# How to predict dataset using NaiveBayes

Tags: machine-learning, nltk, predict, naivebayes

```
x=dataset1[:,1:23] # features
y=dataset1[:,0] #classtypes 
xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.20)
```

My dataset is only letters. There are 23 letters on 1 row.
First letter is classtype and other letters are feauters. I have 2 class --> a,z

Example : a,b,c,d,e,...,g

I will calculate recall,precison and other values but first . I need to find ypred cause those values asking 2 parameters(ytest,ypred) .
How can I predict data using Naive Bayes ?

Comment: what algorithm did you use? GaussianNB from sklearn?

Comment: from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.classify.scikitlearn import SklearnClassifier . And train with .   
nc = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train1) . Train1 is 3/4 of my dataset

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at the `sklearn` documentation for Naive Bayes classifiers: [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html)

Comment: I used classify method and accuracy method but there is no predict or method of other values(precision,f score ) . First of all I need predict method :/. My datas are not integer or float so I cant use Gauss nb

Answer (score 0):

Since you said that you are using `nltk` library, you can do something like the following:

```
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.classify.scikitlearn import SklearnClassifier

x=dataset1[:,1:23] # features
y=dataset1[:,0] #classtypes 
xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.20)

classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(xtrain)

y_predicted = classifier.classify(xtest)
```

---

### Here, `classify` attribute is the same as `predict` attribute in `scikit-learn` algorithms.

---

The available attributes are the following:
[image]

[Documentation here](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/classify/naivebayes.html)

Comment: You're right but I did a mistake. My data is categorized. so I encoded it with binary( true ,false) way. So I cant use train_test_split now . Thanks anyway but I failed. Sorry

Comment: just consider accepting and upvoting my answer because it addresses the initial problem that you described so other people may want to take it into consideration. best regards